# Finding the position of maximum in a Matrix in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia

I want to find the row and the column of the maximum of a matrix.

Let's say `A=[1 20 2;30 400 4;4 50 10]`.

Calling `indmax(A)` gives `5`, but I want to get `(2,2)`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Which version of Julia are you using? `findmax` in Julia 1.1 returns `CartesianIndex` and you can convert it to Tuple if you need to. If you are using an older version of Julia, you can try `ind2sub` like `ind2sub(size(A), indmax(A))`

Comment: `argmax` returns the index only, `findmax` returns a tuple of element value and the index.

Answer (score 2):

Let me basically just repeat what others have mentioned in the comments.

You can use `argmax` to obtain the cartesian position of the maximum in your array.

```
julia> A=[1 20 2;30 400 4;4 50 10];

julia> argmax(A)
CartesianIndex(2, 2)
```

If you really need the `Tuple` `(2,2)`, and you probably do not, you can convert the `CartesianIndex`:

```
julia> convert(Tuple, argmax(A))
(2, 2)
```

Comment: or just `Tuple(argmax(A))` :).

Comment: Yes. But you probably don't want do convert anyways, so maybe the more verbose option is appropriate ;)

Comment: So just to add to @crstnbr's comment: you can use `CartesianIndex` directly to index into an array :).

Comment: argmax() does not work in Julia 0.6, I used ind2sub(A,indmax(A)) and it worked. Thank you all.